# Rails 4 Elastic Beanstalk deployment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting the following error upon deployment from the AWS EB CLI:

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-aa73ca73] Command failed on instance. Return code: 137 Output: (TRUNCATED)...a68506c488392288a70c5f31c658d338f5a7504ccabe8824ee8de2dd6ca94a.png
I, [2015-11-30T14:28:50.159903 #25859]  INFO -- : Writing /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/application-6256e81befb040edb2ea50d5bb17b53518a99712fcea0760a143e8042dfa2326.js
Killed (core dumped). 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-aa73ca73'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have a much better time on EB when I precompile my assets locally. Might be worth a shot.

Comment: Noted, I'll give it a shot. Thanks, I'm dead in the water here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going through my application.js file and played around with removing and adding back required scripts. I narrowed it down to one or more of the following as the culprit.

**Removed:**

```
//= require gmaps/google
//= require rest_in_place
//= require underscore
```

I'll continue to play with it and report back if possible.